# how to get a word before specific keyword in a sentence in Swift?

Tags: swift

> Aipda Karel Sasuit Tubun No.106B, RT.2/RW.1, Ps. Baru, Karawaci, Kota
>   Tangerang, Banten 15112, Indonesia"

I have an string address like that, and I want to get the postal code `15112`  that always positioned right before ', Indonesia'

I am a beginner, I am sorry if this is trivial since I can't find it in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let address = "Aipda Karel Sasuit Tubun No.106B, RT.2/RW.1, Ps. Baru, Karawaci, Kota Tangerang, Banten 15112, Indonesia"

func postcode(from address: String, for area: String) -> String? {
    let array = address.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "").components(separatedBy: " ")
    if let index = array.lastIndex(where: { $0.contains(area) }) {
        return array[index - 1]
    }
    return nil
}

postcode(from: address, for: "Indonesia")
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I think it's a bit of a long winded method but this should work:

```swift
let address = "Aipda Karel Sasuit Tubun No.106B, RT.2/RW.1, Ps. Baru, Karawaci, Kota Tangerang, Banten 15112, Indonesia"
let keyword = "Indonesia"

let components: [String] = address.split(separator: " ").map({ String($0).replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "") })
var postCode = components.first ?? ""

for comp in components {
    if comp == keyword {
        break
    }
    postCode = comp
}

print(postCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression :

```
let str = "Aipda Karel Sasuit Tubun No.106B, RT.2/RW.1, Ps. Baru, Karawaci, Kota Tangerang, Banten 15112, Indonesia"
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: str.utf16.count)
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[0-9]+(?=, Indonesia)")

if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: str, range: range) {
    let subStr = String(str[Range(match.range, in: str)!])
    print(subStr) //15112
}
```